# express-jwt secret should be set error when secret is set

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, express-jwt

In my web app, I'm using express-jwt, but for some reason the secret refuses to be loaded and i do not understand why.

```js
const express = require('express')
import { createClient } from "redis"
import { UserApi } from "./api/users"
const jwtExpress = require('express-jwt')

(async () => {
    //load in dotenv
    require('dotenv').config()


    const app = express()
    const client = createClient()

    //Check redis
    client.on('error', (err) => console.log('Redis Client Error', err))

    //Connect to redis client
    await client.connect()

    //Create API instances
    const ua = new UserApi(client)

    //Initialize middleware
    app.use(express.json())
    app.use(jwtExpress({ secret: "test", algorithms: ['HS256']}).unless({path: ['/token', '/test']}));

    //Create routes
    //test
    app.get("/test", function(req, res) {
        res.send("got")
    })

    //signup - creates user
    app.post("/signup", async function(req, res) {
        const u = {email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password}
        try {
            const {token, refreshToken} = await ua.create(u)
            res.send({token: token, refreshToken: refreshToken, user_email: u.email })
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(400).send({error: error.toString()})
        }
    })

     //login - logs in user
     app.post("/login", async function(req, res) {
        const u = {email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password}
        try {
            const token = await ua.login(u)
            res.send(token)
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(400).send({error: error.toString()})
        }
    })

    //refresh - refreshes token
    app.post('/refresh', async function (req, res) {
        const u = {email: req.body.email, refresh: req.body.refreshToken}
        try {
            const token = await ua.token(u.email, u.refresh)
            res.send(token)
        }  catch (error) {
            res.status(400).send({error: error.toString()})
        }
    })

    app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log("server up")
    })
}) ()
```

Could the async function be a problem? This is a copy of the error I receive:

**if (!options || !options.secret) throw new Error('secret should be set');
^
Error: secret should be set
at module.exports (C:\Users\user\Projects\music-app\backend\node_modules\express-jwt\lib\index.js:20:42)**

Comment: you need a `;` before `(async () => {`, without it its going to invoke whats above which is require('express-jwt')

Comment: Thanks! Why did that work exactly??

Comment: is a pitiful of using an IIFE and not using `;` its seen by js as `const jwtExpress = require('express-jwt')(() => {})()` as said